# MYSQL - Using sub queries and JOIN condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, left-join

I'm trying to learn how to implement sub queries along with Join in MYSQL, 
I'm querying for the problem

**For every language mentioned as having a skill of HIGH, identify the most frequently named MEDIUM language.**

language

### langid  lang

```
AND  Android
C    C
JAV  JAVA
CPP  CPP
```

skill table

### skid value

```
1   High
2   Medium
3   Low
```

strength

### langid     sid skid

```
AND     AW  2
JAVA    AB  1
C       AB  2
C++     AW  1
```

### sid sname

```
AB  AB1
AW  AW1
```

Below are my table structures

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT(
SNAME VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
SID int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(SID)
);

CREATE TABLE LANGUAGE(
LANG VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
LANGID INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(LANGID)
);


CREATE TABLE SKILL(
SKID INT,
VALUE VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY (SKID)
);


CREATE TABLE STRENGTH(
SID INT NOT NULL,
LANGID INT NOT NULL,
SKID INT, 
FOREIGN  KEY (SID) REFERENCES STUDENT (SID),
FOREIGN  KEY (LANGID) REFERENCES LANGUAGE (LANGID),
FOREIGN  KEY (SKID) REFERENCES SKILL (SKID)
);
```

Expected output

```
  prim      | sec       |    count
```

---

```
  JAVA      | C         |        1
  CPP       | Android   |        1
```

I have tried, but i'm unable to implement join,

Comment: can you provide sample input/output, maybe sqlfiddle?

Comment: hey, I have added the sample data!

Answer (score 0):

Without any data, it's hard to say what your criteria will be, but based on the data structure, you would join these tables something like this:

```
select *
from strength st
    join student s
        on s.sid = st.sid
    join language l
        on l.langid = st.langid
    left outer join skill sk
        on sk.skid = st.sklevel
```

The inner joins for student and language are because the foreign key fields are defined as not null, while the sklevel field can be null, so an outer join wouldn't inadvertently screen out any records you want to see.

Comment: morgb - I have added the sample data, Please let me know if you require any detail. For the query you provided, what is the Where condition i need to give?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure I understand the problem that you've posted.  Based on the table structure, the strength table seems to be the crux of the matter, but I don't see any sample data for it.  Regardless, the code above shows how you would join all the tables together, which is what you asked for.  Beyond that, the where clause should really be pretty simple since you know your data.